# Не удается преобразовать лямбда-выражение в требуемый тип делегата

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ado.net

2 ошибки при применении лямды: Не удается преобразовать лямбда-выражение в требуемый тип делегата, так как некоторые возвращаемые типы блока не могут быть неявно преобразованы в возвращаемый тип делегата. + Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.List" в "TodoApi5.Models.MyEventsModel"

Если не трудно, разжуйте...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TodoApi5.Translators;
using TodoApi5.Models;
using TodoApi5.Utility;

namespace TodoApi5.Repository
{
    public class MyEventsDBClient
    {
        public List<MyEventsModel> GetAllMyEvents(string connectstring)
        {
            return SqlHelper.ExtecuteProcedureReturnData<MyEventsModel>(connectstring, "GetEvents", r => r.TranslateAsMyEventsList());

        }
    }
}
```

здесь ошибка

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using TodoApi5.Models;
using TodoApi5.Utility;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Configuration;

namespace TodoApi5.Translators
{
    public static class MyEventsTranslator
    {
        public static List<MyEventsModel> TranslateAsMyEventsList(this SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            var list = new List<MyEventsModel>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(TranslateAsMyEvent(reader, true));
            }
            return list;
        }

        public static MyEventsModel TranslateAsMyEvent(this SqlDataReader reader, bool isList = false)
        {
            if (!isList)
            {
                if (!reader.HasRows)
                    return null;
                reader.Read();
            }
            var item = new MyEventsModel();

            if (reader.IsColumnExists("Id"))
                item.Id = SqlHelper.GetNullableInt32(reader, "Id");

            if (reader.IsColumnExists("EventTitle"))
                item.EventTitle = SqlHelper.GetNullableString(reader, "EventTitle");

            if (reader.IsColumnExists("EventData"))
                item.EventData = SqlHelper.GetNullableDateTime(reader, "EventData");

            if (reader.IsColumnExists("Category"))
                item.CategoryId = SqlHelper.GetNullableInt32(reader, "Category");

            if (reader.IsColumnExists("Picture"))
                item.Picture = SqlHelper.GetNullablePicture(reader, "Picture");

            if (reader.IsColumnExists("EventVenue"))
                item.EventVenue = SqlHelper.GetNullableString(reader, "EventVenue");

            if (reader.IsColumnExists("Discription"))
                item.Discription = SqlHelper.GetNullableString(reader, "Discription");

            if (reader.IsColumnExists("OrganizerId"))
                item.OrganizerId = SqlHelper.GetNullableInt32(reader, "OrganizerId");

            return item;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;

namespace TodoApi5.Utility
{
    public static class SqlHelper
    {
        public static string ExecuteProcedureReturnString
            (string connString, string procName,params SqlParameter[] paramters)
        {
            string result = "";
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = procName;
                    if (paramters != null)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddRange(paramters);
                    }
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    var ret = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (ret != null)
                        result = Convert.ToString(ret);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static TData ExtecuteProcedureReturnData<TData>
            (string connString, string procName,Func<SqlDataReader, TData> translator,params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCommand.CommandText = procName;
                    if (parameters != null)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                    }
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        TData elements;
                        try
                        {
                            elements = translator(reader);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            while (reader.NextResult())
                            { }
                        }
                        return elements;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        ///Methods to get values of   
        ///individual columns from sql data reader  
        #region Get Values from Sql Data Reader  
        public static string GetNullableString(SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
        {
            return reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(colName)) ? null : Convert.ToString(reader[colName]);
        }

        public static DateTime GetNullableDateTime(SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
        {
            return reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(colName)) ? new DateTime(0,0,0) : Convert.ToDateTime(reader[colName]);
        }

        public static int GetNullableInt32(SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
        {
            return reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(colName)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader[colName]);
        }

        public static bool GetBoolean(SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
        {
            return reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(colName)) ? default(bool) : Convert.ToBoolean(reader[colName]);
        }

        public static byte[] GetNullablePicture(SqlDataReader reader, string colName)
        {
            return reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(colName)) ? null : Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(reader[colName]));
        }


        //this method is to check wheater column exists or not in data reader  
        public static bool IsColumnExists(this System.Data.IDataRecord dr, string colName)
        {
            try
            {
                return (dr.GetOrdinal(colName) >= 0);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace TodoApi5.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MyEventsModel
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "EventTitle")]
        public string EventTitle { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "EventData")]
        public DateTime EventData { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Picture")]
        public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "EventVenue")]
        public string EventVenue { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Discription")]
        public string Discription { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "OrganizerId")]
        public int OrganizerId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну так метод у тебя возвращает `MyEventsModel`, а функция требует чтобы возвращалось `List<MyEventsModel>`

Comment: достаточно правильно generic параметр задать `SqlHelper.ExtecuteProcedureReturnData<List<MyEventsModel>>(...)`